# WPF loading viewmodel of a different assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I'm tring to develop an application that's composed by a main application and 3 different modules (assemblies). I'm using ModuleInit.Fody to inizializate the models and Catel for MVVM framework.

My idea was not to reference the modules assembly in my main wpf app.

The main application is build of a menu and a docking panel that hold the tab, the menu is generated looking on a class attribute FunctionalAttribute which scans the referenced assemblies and creates a mapping between a Tag and the viewmodel.

Till now things works quite well since when I click on a menu item it looksup in my dicionary and resolve an instance of the specific type.

When inside a viewmodel defined in a module I try to open another viewmodel (for example an insert popup) I got an error saying the viewlocator can't resolve the view for the specified viewmodel and it has quite sense since the servicelocator doesn't know about that specific viewmodel/view.

Anyone of you got the same problem? I've been told that Prism was too much just to do module composition but I think I'm missing something really stupid (is there a way I can tell the servicelocator to scan and register all viewmodel/types during ModuleInitializer.Initialize?

Thanks

Comment: This is just a wrong convention being used. Enable debug mode as explained in the docs and see what's happening under the hood with the conventions.

Comment: You were right but it was a namespace naming error.. I wrote ViewsModels instead of ViewModels .... thats ok!